# Does exists filter for easy digital download download price

Tags: easy-digital-downloads

I want to implement special discount by price for each download in range of time.
Does exists filter for easy digital download download price?
A filter that change download price that i want.
Thanks

Comment: I find it. I do not need you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "edd_get_download_price" filter in EDD_Download class